# copying someone else's localhost admin panel's data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

So I cloned a rails app repo from bitbucket. It has an admin panel where the user have added several data in the admin panel.

Now, as I cloned the repo, I do not get the admin panel's data so wanted to know If there's any way to get that data as well.

I don't want to add the whole list of data manually in the admin panel.

Comment: get the db backup and import that in your db

Comment: @Deep Can I do that from the bitbucket or I need to ask the other collaborator to provide me his DB

Comment: You need to ask the collaborator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper way to setup some basic data for project is to seed some basic data, like Admin users using rails seeds.rb file. Check rails guides for more info: [Rails guides for seeds](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data)
Check if your project has seeds.rb file and run:

```
bundle exec rake db:seed
```

Comment: It has seeds.rb but that file has not been updated since its creation as suggested by the bitbucket dashboard

Comment: Then you need to create database dump and import it into your database!